# Assimp and visual studio: error 0xc000007b

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, assimp

I have compiled and linked assimp's 32-bit libraries to a program targeting a 32 bit platform with all other 32-bit libraries linked therein. I've placed the relevant 32-bit binaries into the 'Debug' folder. When I compile the program, there are no errors; there are no linker errors either. But, there is a run-time error:

`The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.`

From what I've gathered, this is a bit mismatch whereby there are differences in the bit versions of some libraries. I'm running Windows 7 64-bit. I do not see how there could be a bit mismatch (if that's the cause) since I'm using the 32-bit libraries and binaries. How can I resolve this error?

**Please do not close this question! This isn't a duplicate; I only require help as to how I can resolve this error.**

Comment: With dependency walker.

Comment: How do I use dependency walker?

Comment: Use it to open the executable from the folder it is being currently run from. It will try to load all dependent libraries and will report back to you any errors it encounters such as loading 64bit libraries and which ones.

Comment: Ok, DW reported that at least one module has an unresolved import. I'm really not sure as to the kind of dlls it's asking for. Where do I get DCOMP.DLL for example?

Comment: Some of the errors can be safely ignored, you are looking for the DLL it has marked as being 64bit.

Comment: It doesn't say whether the missing DLLs are 64-bit or not. I still don't know how I can resolve this assimp run-time error.